# Merging ResourceDictionaries changing custom control pathing

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

Net 5 WFP app issue VS v.16.9

My custom control, which is supposed to display a plain  isn't displaying at run. I think I got an idea what's going on but don't know how to fix it.

Merging resource dictionaries in my Generic.xaml file to references the source of my custom control causes the blue squiggly line and mouseover tooltip
***"Cannot locate resource 'ControlsFolder/CustomControl.xaml'"***

If I delete my Merged dictionary, the mouseover tooltip changes to say ***"Projectnamespace.ControlsFolder.CustomControl"***

The tooltipped CustomControl being called in my MainWindow.xaml as follows.

```
<Control:CustomControl/>
```

The Merged of dictionaries that I think is causing the problem is ...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ControlsFolder/CustomContol.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My CustomControls.cs has the constructor below

```
static CustomControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
}
```

Its my understanding that this constuctor searches the Themes/Generic.xaml file to figure out where the location of my customcontrol is to add default metadata to my customcontrol. But I think when I add my merged resource dictionary, its changing the pathing of my CustomControl call to search for my styles in  /ControlFolder/CustomControl.xaml instead of default pathing which should be "Projectnamespace.ControlsFolder.CustomControl".

Or I made a simple mistake that's not intuitive at all for a beginner.

Maybe there is a property I can add to CustomControl that sets the pathing back to the other one. Does anyone have any ideas what the issue is?

But I should be seeing my style display on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Try this URI instead:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/YourProjectName;component/ControlsFolder/CustomContol.xaml" />
```

Comment: That worked, it got rid of the squiggly blue line and changed the tool tip to "Projectnamespace.ControlsFolder.CustomControl".

Interestingly, the reason why my line doesn't didn't display at run time was because it didn't doesn't seem to draw a line. My <line> code is faulty some how.

I was able to show that I could drag and drop and rectangle in from my tool box and draw the rectangle with both lines of reference code.

So the Merged dictionary code wasn't the reason why I couldn't draw on my line, but At least the squiggly blue line is gone.

Comment: Yep, the reason why my line didn't draw is because I'm an idiot. I chose a color at random to test that my custom control worked fine, which happened to be allice blue.

Against my white background, it was too faint to notice. Everything worked fine the whole time, except that squiggly blue line.

Comment: I think what good came out of this is tutorials and youtubers left me with the impression that best practice is to avoid using the drag and drop toolbox because you can't take advantage of the full capability of the software by doing so. But when making a custom control, it seems to make more sense to drag and drop. Visual studio auto populates properties, adds rotation blocks or a great deal of things that you would otherwise never  learn about trying to do things manually. Its just a matter of cleaning up the drag and drop code before I copy and paste it into my custom control xaml.